# jshint error with regular expression

Tags: regex, jshint

Does anyone know why jsHint says this regular expression has a "Bad Escapement"?

```
var regexp = new RegExp('^http(s)?:\/\/([a-z]+\.)?(' + this.opts.domain + ')', 'ig');
```

It's complaining about the escaped period `\.`

The regex still works without escaping the period. My goal is to find if a URL contains a given domain name, http://rubular.com/r/5U7kVjhleu

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you construct a regex from a string, you need to double the backslashes (and you don't need to escape the slashes):

```
var regexp = new RegExp('^http(s)?://([a-z]+\\.)?(' + this.opts.domain + ')', 'ig');
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer! This is the first I heard of having to do a double backslash in a regex string to escape characters. I've been doing it wrong all these years lol.